# Passing a multidimensional array as an argument to a multidimensional slice parameter

Tags: arrays, function, go, slice

Say in Go I have a multidimensional array in my calling function, and I'd like to pass that array to a function, and more specifically to a parameter that is a multidimensional slice. Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is p[assing a multidimensional array as an argument to a multidimensional slice parameter] possible [?]

No.

You must convert all inner arrays to slices first. (Or just don't use arrays but slices only.)